# Possible to bind kendo ui grid custom dropdown to an id instead of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui grid and in that grid i have a dropdownlist. As for now it works in the way that it gets the name of the customer and adds it to the dropdown but when the dropdown is not "active" it just shows the customerId.

This is my object that i use in the grid:

```
  public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int MinimumCost { get; set; }
    public int MaximumCost { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
```

What i want to do is a dropdown that is connected to CustomerId but shows customername in the dropdown. This is the code for my grid:

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
   var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/DiscountPromotion/Get',
            dataType: "json",
        },
        update: {
            url: '/DiscountPromotion/Update',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        destroy: {
            url: '/DiscountPromotion/Delete',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        create: {
            url: '/DiscountPromotion/Add',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read") {
                return JSON.stringify({ discountPromotionDto: options });
            }
        },

    },
    pageSize: 10,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { type: "number" },
                Code: { type: "string" },
                StartDate: { type: "date" },
                EndDate: { type: "date" },
                MinimumCost: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0 } },
                MaximumCost: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0 } },
                Quantity: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0 }},
                CustomerId: { type: "number" },
                CountryCode: { type: "string" },
                Discount: { type: "number" },
                ModelName: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    }
});
$("#discountpromotiongrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: datasource,
    batch: true,
    toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel", { name: "genCode", text: "Generate Code", click: function(e) {
        return false;
    }}],
    height: 400,
    navigatable: true,
    selectable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    columns: [
    {
        field: "ModelName",
        title: "ModelName",
        editor: modelNameDropDown,
        template: "#=ModelName#",
        width: 150
    },
    {
        field: "Code",
        title: "Code",
        width: 150
    },
    {
        field: "StartDate",
        title: "StartDate",
        template: '#= kendo.toString(StartDate,"yyyy-MM-dd") #',
        format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",
        parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd"],
        width: 120
    },
    {
        field: "EndDate",
        title: "EndDate",
        template: '#= kendo.toString(EndDate,"yyyy-MM-dd") #',
        format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",
        parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd"],
        width: 120
    },
    {
        field: "MinimumCost",
        title: "MinCost",
        width: 100,
        format: "{0:n0}"
    },
    {
        field: "MaximumCost",
        title: "MaxCost",
        width: 100,
        format: "{0:n0}"
    },
    {
        field: "Quantity",
        title: "Quantity",
        width: 80,
        format: "{0:n0}"
    },
    {
        field: "CustomerId",
        title: "Customer",
        editor: customerDropDown,
        template: "#=CustomerId#",
        width: 150
    },
    {
        field: "CountryCode",
        title: "CountryCode",
        editor: countryCodeDropDown,
        template: "#=CountryCode#",
        width: 120
    },
    {
        field: "Discount",
        format: "{0:p0}",
        editor: function (container, options) {
            $("<input name='Discount'>")
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoNumericTextBox(
              {
                  min: 0,
                  max: 1.0,
                  step: 0.01
              });
        },
        width: 100
    },
    {
        command: "destroy",
        title: "&nbsp;",
        width: 120
    }],
    editable: true
});



function modelNameDropDown(container, options) {
    $('<input required data-text-field="ModelName" data-value-field="ModelName" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: true,
            optionLabel: "Select model...",
            dataSource: {
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/DiscountPromotion/GetModelNamesByCustomerId',
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}

function customerDropDown(container, options) {
    $('<input required data-text-field="CustomerName" data-value-field="CustomerId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: true,
            optionLabel: "Select model...",
            dataSource: {
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/DiscountPromotion/GetSuppliersCustomersByCustomerId',
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}

function countryCodeDropDown(container, options) {
    $('<input required data-text-field="CountryCode" data-value-field="CountryCode" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: true,
            optionLabel: "Select model...",
            dataSource: {
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/DiscountPromotion/GetCountryCodesBySuppliersCustomers',
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}

$(".k-grid-genCode", "#discountpromotiongrid").bind("click", function (ev) {
    var text = generateCode();
    var grid = $("#discountpromotiongrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var row = grid.select();
    var data = grid.dataItem(row);
    data.dirty = true;
    data.Code = text;
    $('#discountpromotiongrid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
    //$(".k-grid-edit-row").find("input[name='Code']").val(text);

});

function generateCode() {

     var n = 8;

    var text = '';
    var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }

    return text;
   }

    });
```

The object of the list that the dropdownlist get-method gets looks like this:

```
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerERPId { get; set; }
```

So how do i bind the data to CustomerId in the grid but show the value of CustomerName?

Comment: try with dataTextField and DatavalueField as,  .kendoDropDownList({..., dataTextField: "textfieldname", dataValueField: "valuefieldname",..});

Comment: that doesn't work. I guess thats kind of the same as it already is in my dropdown with this code: <input required data-text-field="CustomerName" data-value-field="CustomerId"

Answer (score 0):

The grid doesn't know the customer name which corresponds to a CustomerId. The dropdownlist populates with that list during editing. To make it work you need to load the customers and set the template of the column:

```
{
    field: "CustomerId",
    title: "Customer",
    editor: customerDropDown,
    template: "#=customerNames[CustomerId]#",
    width: 150
}
```

Where customerNames is something like this

```
var customerNames = { 1: "Foo", 2: "Bar" }; // key is CustomerID value is CustomerName
```

Comment: I'm not sure i follow you here. I return an list of the object    

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerERPId { get; set; } 

but in you example i should make my own object as a collection of key-value-pairs?

Comment: Yes. You need to have this object available for the grid otherwise you can't show the customer names - they are not part of the data item which the grid is bound to.